# Looking for a tool to plan network/vlan topologies

Tags: networking, vlan, topology

I'm looking for a tool (desktop or web-based) that we can use to plan our network topologies using VLAN's. Something capable of defining switches, and mapping VLAN's to the ports and allowing use to map and review the VLAN layout.

I'm not expecting any kind automatic management, so something vendor-neutral would be perfect. Just a way to keep tabs on a VLAN setup over multiple switches.

Answer (score 4):

Was waiting for someone to come up with an answer as i really want to know it too.

The 2 options i've found and now tried are.

[Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), works on windows/mac/linux or
[Network Notepad](http://www.networknotepad.com/), works on windows only

Have to say i found both a bit old school, a little bit clunky, though they are both still being developed. Dia stores it's diagrams as XML but will export to WMF, SVG, PNG & EPS. NN saves it's files in a text file, of which an old version is spec'd on the website.

Dia also had reasonable network objects in it's library of devices, but it doesnt' seem to cover some of the larger/newer switches. You may have to create some of your own.

Between the two, i'd plump for Dia as your visio replacement.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll check both out. Was hoping for a tool that specifically understands VLAN topologies and helps you map, reference and understand what is going on.